# sagemaker endpoint content_type can't set attribute

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create a fraud detection model by following this notebook from aws:

https://github.com/awslabs/fraud-detection-using-machine-learning/blob/master/source/notebooks/sagemaker_fraud_detection.ipynb

In the section "Host Random Cut Forest', at the line

```
rcf_predictor.content_type = 'text/csv'
```

I get this error:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-bd790d3851f9> in <module>
      1 from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer, json_deserializer
      2 
----> 3 rcf_predictor.content_type = 'text/csv'
      4 rcf_predictor.serializer = csv_serializer
      5 rcf_predictor.accept = 'application/json'

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

What is this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( remove line 3 with this one)

```
rcf_predictor.__setattr__(rcf_predictor.content_type, "text/csv")
```

I just try to set attribute diffrently.